# QFile::copy weird behaviour

Tags: c++, qt

QFile::copy won't copy file from my resources. My code is:

```
QTemporaryFile file;
file.setFileTemplate("/tmp/XXXXXX.wav");
file.open();

qDebug() << QFile::copy(":/busy.wav", file.fileName());
```

Displays "False". But if I set destination name manually, say for example

```
qDebug() << QFile::copy(":/busy.wav", "blabla.wav");
```

or

```
 qDebug() << QFile::copy(":/busy.wav", file.fileName() + ".wav");
```

it works fine then. What is wrong with this "copy" or with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is simply because `QFile` does not overwrite existing files (from the documentation):

> Note that if a file with the name newName already exists, copy() returns false (i.e. QFile will not overwrite it).

The most simple solution would be to make a dedicated function to create tmp filenames. Since `QTemporaryFile` deletes the file when destroyed, this will work fine:

```
QString generateName()
{
    QTemporaryFile file;
    file.setFileTemplate("/tmp/XXXXXX.wav");
    file.open();//QTemporaryFile creates the file. QFile::copy will not be able to overwrite it, so you will need to delete it first.
    file.close();
    return file.fileName();
}//QTemporaryFile gets destroyed, and deletes the file. Now QFile::copy will work fine.

int main()
{
    QFile::copy(your_resource_file, generateName());
}
```

Comment: I know that. QTemporaryFile generates unique file name each time so problem is not in this

Comment: @user2123079, no it doesnt. When you `open` the temporary file after using `setFileTempate`, a new tmp file is created with a unique name that is based on your template. Then you try to use `QFile::copy`, but the temporary file is still there, so you can't overwrite it. You need to either delete it manually, or destroy the `QTemporaryFile` object for that file to be deleted; after that, copying will work fine.

Comment: Oh, damn it! I understood the problem. Seems I'm very tired already =) Thank you very much! God bless you :D

Comment: Problem with this solution is that there is no `QTemporaryFile` referencing the "temporary file". So you will need to delete it manually when the file isn't needed anymore.